# CSS Hover using jQuery to fade

Tags: jquery, css

I have a simple link that changes when the user hovers, so something along these lines:

```
a.mylink {
    background: url(..) top left no-repeat;
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}

a.mylink:hover,
a.mylink.jqHover {
    background: url(..) top left no-repeat;
    color: red;
}
```

**Changed my mind about what I want to happen, basically I want to make it so that when a user hovers the link it will do the :hover stuff but slowly instead of instantly. So like a transition effect. I've made it into a class to make it easier to deal with the hover malarkey, so I'm guessing a simple add class and remove class but with some sort of fade timer?**

I'm effectively trying to do this:

```
$('a.mylink').hover(
            function () {
                $(this).addClass('.jqHover');
            },
            function () {
                $(this).removeClass('.jqHover');
            }
        );
```

But I want it to fade between the two classes!

/////////////////////// EDIT:

This is the code I have at the moment -->

```
$("ul.BrightLozenges li a").hover(

        function() {
            $(this).switchClass('Normal','Special',200,'easeOutBounce');
        }, 
        function() {    
            $(this).switchClass('Special','Normal',200,'easeOutBounce');
        });
```

Which works fine, but I want to make it fade in and fade out, tried using 'fade' as the transition but it doesn't work?

Comment: you can't fade a background, unless it's a dom element...

Comment: check the updated answer you require to use toggle function for that

Comment: How will toggle do it? Can you show a better example

Answer (score 1):

You can create a sprite image and animate it's background position if this meets your needs.

Have a look at this post http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

Other than that, you have to fade out the whole element, add a class with the new BG, and fade in the element. If you have it happen quite fast (i.e. 200/300ms) the transition should be quite good.

You can try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mylink").hover(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(200).addClass("jqHover").fadeIn(300);
    },
        $(this).fadeOut(200).removeClass("jqHover").fadeIn(300);
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [switchClass](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions#switchClass) method in [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

```
$(elem).switchClass('currentClass', 'newClass', 500);
```

Comment: This works the best so far, but it's not switching back to my default state! Would it be possible for you to amend the code so that a user hovers it fades to the new class and then back to the other class when the hovers out. Thanks.

Comment: Can i see the css for the two classes Normal and Special?

Answer (score 0):

use : [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

following is example also availble on the link page pasted by me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  ul { margin-left:20px; color:blue; }
  li { cursor:default; }
  span { color:red; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <ul>
    <li>Milk</li>
    <li>Bread</li>
    <li class='fade'>Chips</li>

    <li class='fade'>Socks</li>
  </ul>
<script>
$("li").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).append($("<span> ***</span>"));
  }, 
  function () {
    $(this).find("span:last").remove();
  }
);



//li with fade class
$("li.fade").hover(function(){$(this).fadeOut(100);$(this).fadeIn(500);});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit :**

use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) as used in below function will do the work for you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
p { background:#dad;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:16px; }
</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button>Toggle 'em</button>

<p>Hiya</p>
<p>Such interesting text, eh?</p>
<script>
$("button").click(function () {
$("p").toggle("slow");
});    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```